# Spring Boot: Can not POST into ManyToMany Relation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have two Entities `Meal` and `Mealplan` that are in a @ManyToMany Relation. Each Mealplan can have different Meals and each Meal can be in multiple Mealplans.

```
@Entity
public class Meal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private String type;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "mealsPerWeek")
private List<Mealplan> mealplan;
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Mealplan {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private int week;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<Meal> mealsPerWeek;
```

Since I have added the ManyToMany Relation, I can't add a Meal by @Postmapping it into the API.

**MealController**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/meal")
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
public class MealController {

    @PostMapping
    public void addMeal(@RequestBody Meal meal) {
        mealRepository.save(meal);
    }
```

The MealRepository Class extends the JPARepository.

Whenever I want to post something into my entity like:

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "name": "Test",
    "price": 3.50,
    "type": "with Meat"
}
```

the following error appears: 
`"could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [PRIMARY]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement"`

Adding via INSERT INTO works as usual.

Comment: What are you trying to do:edit an existing record or add a new Entity? Have you enabled SQL logging. What is the SQL generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem for me. I noticed, that `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` does not set the ID field to "auto increment". I've set it to `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` and insert new data without using the ID like this (as @Ravi Sharma mentioned):

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "price": 3.50,
    "type": "with Meat"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your entity mapping, the Id field is defined as auto-generated. In your request Json, Id is passed as 10. Are you trying to insert or update?. You can try below request JSON and see if insert works.

```
{
    "name": "Test",
    "price": 3.50,
    "type": "with Meat",
    "mealplan": []

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, since you have used 'mappedBy' in entity Meal, hence that is the mapped entity, and hence MealPlan becomes the owner entity, i.e. it is responsible for maintaining associations.

You also need to create another table, let's call **MealMapping** to store the mappings of Meal and MealPlan having fields as meal_id and mealplan_id.

Now you need to define @JoinTable in the owner entity.

```
@Entity
public class Mealplan {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
private int week;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="MealMapping", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="ID")}, 
inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="ID")})  
private List<Meal> mealsPerWeek;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Also, it works by INSERT query since you've defined many-to-many relation in hibernate and not on database tables.Hence, constraints only apply when you try to insert using hibernate.

Comment: All these things are optional. The original code will generate use default table names and columns if they are not specified so this is  not the issue here.

Comment: what you mention with "another table" is already done by the @ManyToMany Relation. It creates the table "mealplan_meals_per_week" and contains the meal_ids and the mealplan_ids's.